# Proof of a statement regarding osculating spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, curves

> Let $r: I \subseteq\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^n$ with I interval be a $C^k$ function such that $r'(t),...,r^{(k)}(t)$ are linearly independent for every $t\in I$, define $V_i(t) = r(t) + Span(r'(t),...,r^{(i)}(t))$ for $i\le k$.
>
> Prove that the definition of $V_i$ does not depend on the parametrization of r, that is if $\gamma =r(\phi)$ with $\phi:J\subseteq \mathbb{R} \to I$ (J interval) bijective such that $\gamma$ is $C^k$ and $\phi'(s)\ne0,\forall s \in J$, then $V_i(\phi(s))= \gamma(s)+Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(i)}(s))$.

I have some trouble proving this, for $k\gt3$ the explicit expression of $\gamma^{(k)}$ is not very useful; I've tried induction, but I'm stuck on the inductive step.

Could you give me a hint? Thanks

Edit:

I proved that $\gamma^{(i)}=\sum_{j=1}^{i}\alpha_j r^{(j)}$ for some $\alpha_j$ with $\alpha_i=(\phi')^i$.

Now the case $i=1$ is immediate. If we assume that $V_i = \gamma(s)+Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(i)}(s))$ we have $Span(r'(t),...,r^{(i+1)}(t))= Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(i)}(s), r^{(i+1)}(\phi(s))) = Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(i+1)}(s))$ because $\gamma^{(i+1)}$ is a linear combination of $\gamma^{(j)}$, $1\le j\le i$, and $r^{(i+1)}$ and the coefficient of the last one is $\ne0$. We can conclude that $V_{i+1}(\phi(s))= \gamma(s)+Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(i+1)}(s))$ for all $s \in J$.

Edit':

I proved that for every integer $k \ge 1$ we have $\gamma^{(k)}(s)=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\alpha_j(s)r^{(j)}(t)$ where $t=\phi(s)$, moreover $\alpha_k(s)=(\phi(s)')^k$ (of course $\alpha_j$ depends also on $k$).

If $k=1$ we have $V_1(t)=r(t)+Span(r'(t))$ and $\gamma(s)+Span(\gamma'(s))=r(t)+Span(\phi'(s)r'(t))$, since $\phi'(s)\ne 0$ we have the equality $V_1(t)= \gamma(s)+Span(\gamma'(s))$.

Let $k\ge 1$ be an integer and assume the thesis holds for it. We need to prove $V_i(t)= \gamma(s)+Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(i)}(s))$ for $1\le i \le k+1$; if $1\le i\le k$ the equality follows by induction.
If $i=k+1$ then $\gamma^{(k+1)}(s)=\sum_{j=1}^{k}\alpha_j(s)r^{(j)}(t)+(\phi'(s))^{k+1}r^{(k+1)}(t) \in Span(r'(t),...,r^{(k+1)}(t))$, but $\gamma^{(k+1)}(s) \notin Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(k)}(s))$ and $Span(r'(t),...,r^{(k)}(t))=Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(k)}(s))$.
Therefore $Span(\gamma'(s),...,\gamma^{(k+1)}(s))  \le Span(r'(t),...,r^{(k+1)}(t))$ and they have the same dimension, hence equality holds (or we can use symmetry).

Comment: Hint #1: the map $\phi:J\to I$ needs to have a non-vanishing derivative.

Comment: You're right to try induction. Using the chain rule and the product rule, you should be able to show that $\gamma^{(k)}(s) \in\text{Span}(r'(t),\dots,r^{(k)}(t))$ for $t=\phi(s)$. And, of course, you can interchange the roles of $s$ and $t$, eventually.

Comment: Thanks for the hints, what do you think of my proof?

Comment: First, you shouldn't use the index $i$ in defining $\alpha_j$. I believe your argument shows inclusion of the spans, not equality. [Well, your discussion of the nonzero coefficient should actually establish equality, but you haven't shown any details.] Nevertheless, as I indicated, you can reverse the roles of $r$ and $\gamma$ to get the other inclusion and, hence, equality. (By the way, you need to ping me in order for me to know you've written something addressed to me.)

Comment: @TedShifrin I've rewrote the proof, how does it seem?